# Is it possible to get data out of .lightspeedBackup file without using Lightspeed POS?

Tags: database

I have a Lightspeed POS 3.x Backup file. I would like to abstract the database out of it. Is this at all possible? The file extension of the backup file is .lightspeedBackup.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to just rename it as a .zip and extract it. Once you do you should have several directories and files with all your data in it.

Not sure why they try to hide that or are using their own extension.